# Creating folded corner card using css

Tags: css

I want to create a card which is shown in below image. I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashok_dongare/uDbFC/) where I created a sample card. The below code creates only plane rectangular card

```
.card {
    height: 300px;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 4px threedshadow;   
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
  }
```

[image]

Please any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #97C02F;
}
.card:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #658E15 #fff;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/7kMMc/1/)

You can play with the above and try using `.card:after` for the bottom left and right corners.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are using here colored card so able to distinguish card from white background. But my requirement is white card on white background. So how could we do this?

Comment: There are many variants of white color, you can pick from here:http://html-color-codes.info/ How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/7kMMc/2/. Another thing you can try out is to keep the `div` white, but create its borders with `grey` color or something dark.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Now it suits my requirement with little changes in color-scheme.